# Deleting using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete some data from a table. I want to delete the data that is not included in the inner join

My query so far:

```
 DELETE *how do you say delete what wasn't included in the inner join?*
 from dbo.Cloudpie c
 inner join dbo.cake p
 on c.cakeid = p.cakeid
where cakeid > 1
```

Thanks in advance for all and any help provided :)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
DELETE c
FROM dbo.Cloudpie c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.cake p
    ON c.cakeid = p.cakeid
WHERE p.cakeid IS NULL AND c.cakeid > 1
```

or even simpler and less error-prone (on nullable columns) using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE c
FROM dbo.Cloudpie c
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.cake p
                  WHERE p.cakeid = c.cakeid ) 
AND c.cakeid > 1
```

worth reading: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: +1 . . . although you are missing the `where` condition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thanks for noting, edited it to include the `Where cakeid > 1`.

Comment: I added in the where clause (I provided an example query) after he probably didn't see it :). Thank you very much tim I'll accept your answer when it lets me :).